How to import this csv file with "@" as delimiter using readr
This is my excel files and I would like to import it using the readr::read_csv() file or maybe other function using "," and "@" as delimiter
Describing my .csv file:
Columns <-  CoreId,Identifier,type,rightsHolder,creator,accessURI,format,variantLiteral,license

    First row <- 296911@OBS,https://observation.org/photos/9999/,StillImage,André den Ouden,Andre den Ouden,https://observation.org/photos/9999.jpg,image/jpeg,Best Quality,All rights reserved

Second row <- 45689812@OBS,https://observation.org/photos/999999/,StillImage,Hans van Kersbergen,Hans van Kersbergen,https://observation.org/photos/999999.jpg,image/jpeg,Best Quality,CC BY-NC-ND 4.0


I need to import this .csv file and I use this:
read_csv(file = 'myfile.csv',progress = TRUE)

This is the output:

As you can see, the '@' symbol is meant to separate one column, but it's currently merged with the first column.
Is it possible to explicitly treat '@' as a delimiter to separate the columns?
Any help would be appreciated.

You asked exactly the same question a few days ago. I wrote a long comment explaining how this can be easily corrected afterwards using base R functions or directly using scan(), read.table(). Why the deletion?

@Friede I deleted to edit the question. Sorry.

@GregorThomas yes you are totally right. It was a silly mistake

@Laura, one more nag: it's best to include information in text format when you can rather than as images (although to be fair your question does have all of the strictly necessary information in text format ...)

If the data is already loaded, i.e.
mydata=read_csv(file = 'myfile.csv',progress = TRUE)

has been executed, you might want to correct it:
cbind.data.frame(
  t(list2DF(strsplit(mydata$CoreId, "@"))) |> `colnames<-`(c("Core", "Id")), 
  mydata[-1]) |> 
  `row.names<-`(NULL) # cosmetics

# or (writing less)
cbind(do.call("rbind", strsplit(mydata$CoreId, "@")), mydata[-1]) |> 
  `names<-`(c("Core", "Id", names(mydata[-1]))) 

giving
      Core  Id                             Identifier       type        rightsHolder
1   296911 OBS   https://observation.org/photos/9999/ StillImage     André den Ouden
2 45689812 OBS https://observation.org/photos/999999/ StillImage Hans van Kersbergen


Input
(truncated)
mydata = structure(
  list(
    CoreId = c("296911@OBS", "45689812@OBS"),
    Identifier = c(
      "https://observation.org/photos/9999/",
      "https://observation.org/photos/999999/"
    ),
    type = c("StillImage", "StillImage"),
    rightsHolder = c("André den Ouden", "Hans van Kersbergen")
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -2L)
)


I think tidyr::separate will do what you want.
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
writeLines(c("col1,col2,col3",
             "123@OBS,1,2",
             "456@OBS,3,4"), con = "tmp.csv")
read_csv("tmp.csv") |> separate(col1, into = c("col1A", "col1B"), sep = "@")

According to the help file

‘separate()’ has been superseded in favour of ‘separate_wider_position()’ and ‘separate_wider_delim()’

so technically separate above should be separate_wider_delim ...

superseded is not the same as deprecated.  superseded functions will continue to be available unlike deprecated ones which will not be.

Oh wow, that’s a terrible … er, “supersession” (?).

I know that superseded is not the same as deprecated, but I generally feel it's best practice (if one can stand it) to move away from superseded functions. (It's a little frustrating when the only options are "superseded" or "experimental" though, which does happen ...)
